# XML and CSS: Text doesn't rotate

Tags: xml, css

I want to rotate the XML node c but nothing happens and I don't know why.

HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="cssdata.css"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            This text should be rotated
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
c
{
                transform: rotate(45deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom element is by default `inline` and for `transform` to work, it should be `inline-block` or `block`, so you'll need to change it.

*Side note, you can read more about [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) here, as they also might need to be registered properly as well*

```css
c {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left top
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="cssdata.css"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            This text should be rotated
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```